# Convert character string into columns of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, character, row, bioinformatics

I have a character vector that looks like this:

```
c("S01_28819_W0D0_Unpr", "S01_28819_W0D1_Unpr", "S01_28819_W0D3_Unpr")
```

What I would like to do is split each entry using "_" as the separator then add those to a new dataframe so that it would look like this:

```
      admin  type time cond
    1   S01 28819 W0D0 Unpr
    2   S01 28819 W0D1 Unpr
    3   S01 28819 W0D3 Unpr
```

So far, I've initialized a new dataframe and then used a for loop to split each entry.

```
    df <- data.frame(admin=character(), type=character(), time=character(), cond=character())

    for (i in qwerty) {
        i <- unlist(strsplit(i, "_"))
    }
```

Where I'm stuck is in how to add the split character strings to the dataframe. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use `read.table` with `sep = '_'`:

```
c("S01_28819_W0D0_Unpr", "S01_28819_W0D1_Unpr", "S01_28819_W0D3_Unpr") -> string

read.table(text = string, sep = '_')
   V1    V2   V3   V4
1 S01 28819 W0D0 Unpr
2 S01 28819 W0D1 Unpr
3 S01 28819 W0D3 Unpr
```

---

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(string, "_")))
   X1    X2   X3   X4
1 S01 28819 W0D0 Unpr
2 S01 28819 W0D1 Unpr
3 S01 28819 W0D3 Unpr
```